# knowing the Store object corresponding to the StoreGet object

Tags: python, python-3.x, simpy

i have multiple process each one has its proper store with which it will communicate with a single process at a random interval of time. for that i used the Environment.any_of(all_stores.get()), this will return a dictionary with where the keys are StoreGet object and the values are the values in the stores.

I want to have a way to know for every entry in the dictionary the store (and if not possible the process) corresponding.

```
import simpy,random
def worker(ident,env,sstore):
    while True:
        yield env.timeout(random.randint(0,10))
        # calculation
        sstore.put(random.random())
def mon(env,lstores):
    while True:
        resultat=yield env.any_of([s.get() for s in lstores])
        # calculation depending of the values and the source 
        # need to know the source of each information 
env=simpy.Environment()
lstores=[simpy.Store(env,capacity=1) for x in range(5)]
lworkers=[env.process(worker((i+1),env,lstores[i])) for i in range(5)]
env.process(mon(env,lstores))
env.run(until=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

`evt.resource` and `evt.proc` are your friends.

They are undocumented and defiend in the base `Put`/`Get` event classes: https://bitbucket.org/simpy/simpy/src/e84015dcf54c05868712683fb1d9fcfd2cc44089/src/simpy/resources/base.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#base.py-29